# Is there a webhook manager?

Tags: node.js, backend, webhooks, apigee

I have to implement webhooks in my API. There is an webhook manager? 
That can manage suscriptions, users, etc.

Otherwise, Is there an library that can help me to develop webhooks? 
I'm using nodejs.

Thank you!

I did a quick search and I only found this nodejs library
https://www.npmjs.com/package/webhooks
Nothing about a webhook manager.

Answer (score -1):

I did some research about a year ago and there isn't much out there.  It's pretty easy to set up.  You just need a database table (or list) of URLs to hit when something occurs.

You can make it more complicated, but at its essence, it's just a list of URLs.